# How to avoid over lapping stack navigator in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using react navigator for redirect one page to another but while using Tab navigation and react navigator together can't set header title.
For example i have `app.js` with following code

```
import Dash from './components/Dash';
export const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Dash:{ screen: Dash},
});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <SimpleApp />

    );
  }
}
```

The dash.js contain following code

```
 class Notes extends React.Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Some title',
      };
          render(){
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Details!</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    class Message extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Message!</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }


    export default TabNavigator(//some code);
```

Actual problem is one stack navigator overlapping another. How to solve this problem? any other way to set header title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope i understood it right. but i think that is what you are looking vor.

```
export default createStackNavigator({
 Dash: {
  screen: Dash,
  navigationOptions: { header: 'Dash title'}
 },
Home: {
 navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({header: null}),
 screen: createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Tab1: {
      screen: tab1,
      navigationOptions: { title: 'tab1' }
    },
    Tab2: {
      screen: tab2,
      navigationOptions: {title: 'tab2'}
    },
   },

  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
       tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'black',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
         labelStyle: {
           fontSize: 25,
           fontWeight: 'bold',
           padding: 12
         }
       }
     })
   }
 )
},
```

Comment: Thank you..Your code not worked but which helped me to get the result.

Comment: im glad i could help
feel free to edit my post to your solution to maybe help people with that problem in the future

Comment: Added title from app.js and removed stack navigation in dash.js